# CodeIgniter Datamapper ORM: Error with relationship by using get()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

i have a problem with datamapper orm in codeigniter... :O

my first model:

```
class Mil_widget extends DataMapper {

    // Insert related models that Mil_widget can have more than one of.
    var $has_many = array(

        'mil_relationship' => array(
            'join_table' => 'mil_fields_mil_widgets'
        )
    );
}
```

and this is my other model:

```
class Mil_relationship extends DataMapper {

    // Insert related models that Mil_widget can have more than one of.
    var $has_many = array(

        'mil_widget' => array(
            'join_table' => 'mil_fields_mil_widgets'
        )
    );
}
```

if I di this it works and saves the right database entry:

```
$w = new Mil_widget(1);
$r = new Mil_relationship(1);
$w->save($r);
```

But if I do this i get error:

```
$w->mil_relationship->get();
```

And this is the error:

> DataMapper Error: 'mil_widget' is not a valid parent relationship for
>   Mil_relationship. Are your relationships configured correctly?

THANK YOU!